# Multiple Assignees to Azure DevOps task

Tags: devops

How do we enable multiple assignees to Azure DevOps tasks? Or is there any feature to add followers to Azure DevOps tasks.

Comment: If I knew how to do it, I would vote to close this ticket. This seems like something that you can simply google for

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge this feature (to add multiple owners/asignees to a work item) currently does not exist with Azure DevOps.

One way that you're team could accomplish this is by using tags (however this wouldn't be ideal).

Of course you could have each individual create their own tasks but would not be ideal as data would be duplicated (waste).

You can subscribe to a work item by 'following' it, where that individual would be notified via email when the work item is modified. Documentation here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/add-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

You could request that Microsoft add this feature to their roadmap at the link below:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html